# How can I convert a simple image from the disk to OpenCV mat file?

Tags: python, opencv, rabbitmq

I need to send the image with RabbitMQ and the only way I found is:

```
f = open("asd.jpg","rb")
img = f.read()
f.close()
```

Than I can send the `img`.

I would like to process the sent image where I received it so how can I convert it to an OpenCV mat file?

Here is how I receive the file:

```
def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    print "Recieved"
    cv2.imshow('Message', body)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

*Send.py*:

```
import pika
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('asd.jpg')

#Establish connection
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters('localhost'))
channel = connection.channel()

channel.exchange_declare(exchange='image_exch', type='fanout')

channel.basic_publish(exchange='image_exch', routing_key='', body=img)

print "[*] Sent"

connection.close()
```

*Receive.py*:

```
import pika
import cv2

#Establish connection
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters('localhost'))
channel = connection.channel()

channel.exchange_declare(exchange='image_exch', type='fanout')
result = channel.queue_declare(exclusive=True)
queue_name = result.method.queue

channel.queue_bind(exchange='image_exch', queue=queue_name)

def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    print "Recieved"
    cv2.imshow('Message', body)
    cv2.waitKey(0)

channel.basic_consume(callback, queue=queue_name, no_ack=True)
print(' [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C')
channel.start_consuming()
```

Comment: Why don't you just read the image using opencv? It will be read as a numpy array.

Comment: So first I have to save it and than read it again with openCV? Or I don't understand.

Comment: Use "imdecode"....

Answer (score 0):

So after a few tries I managed to **solve** my problem.

This is how I did it:

```
#Read the image as binary
f = open("picture.jpg","rb")
rawImg= f.read()
f.close()

#Convert the raw image to a numpy array for further processing
npImage = np.fromstring(rawImg, dtype='uint8')
#Convert the numpy array to an OpenCV image type
img = cv2.imdecode(npImage, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
cv2.imshow('Recieved message', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

And this works perfectly with RabbitMQ and OpenCV. Just read the image as binary file with the sender script then send it. After you receive the message just convert it and you are done.